# Eclipse web.xml editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I have Helios Service Release 2 installed with WTP tools.  I created a simple dynamic web project.  When I open web.xml, which opens with default XML editor, it shows only two tabs:Design(Standard XML tab) & Source.

When I worked with Rational Software Architect in past, it opened web.xml with tabs like 'Servlet', 'References' so on to let you easily edit various parts of web.xml in visual point & click manner.

Is this possible with Eclipse?

btw, I tried 'Open with' menu option but couldn't find appropriate editor for web.xml

Thanks

Comment: e.g. [link MyEclipse plugin](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webxmleditor/)

Comment: I am using eclipse jee-photon, you can edit web.xml the clicking on the left column. If you right click, it will have a drop down menu with: Remove, Add Attribute,Add child, ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install JBoss tools through Eclipse marketplace to have a complete web.xml editor. You don't have to install all the plugins. In my case I just installed the "Context and Dependency Injection Tools"

Comment: Thank you.  This is free tool & does seem to do same job as paid tool in my link above.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse currently does not have this functionality. IBM did not donate this part of the tooling from Rational Software Artifact when it seeded Eclipse Web Tools Project.

Note that there is an effort that is just getting started to implement these editors at Eclipse, but you are not going to be able to use the fruit of that work until Juno release in the Summer of 2012.

In the meantime, you will need to use plain XML editor or seek third-party solutions, such as MyEclipse. Note that MyEclipse is not compatible with Eclipse WTP. It is separate tooling stack for web app development.