# How to open web.xml as tree view in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, web.xml

I m working on a project in eclipse, I have generated web.xml for it. How to view web.xml as tree view. Currently I can only view it as Design and Source.

[image]

Comment: The _Design_ page of the XML editor usually shows the elements as a tree. Please clarify your question. Also these posts may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035223/eclipse-web-xml-editor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912087/eclipse-plug-in-to-edit-web-xml-in-java-ee

Comment: I have installed JBoss, but still not able to get tree view.

Comment: Did you try the _Open With_ menu from the context menu of the web.xml file? If you have JBoss installed, there should be a menu entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's the only thing you can get, but `design` allows you to have a tree-like navigation

Comment: I have installed JBoss, how to get tree view?

Comment: Then it should be avaible when doing `right click on the file > open with > others... > find something like jboss tree editor`